# XElement with System.Data.Linq.Binary

Tags: xml, linq-to-sql, binary, xelement

I am making an XElement with an element that has LINQ.Binary in it..

The line looks like:

```
new XElement("Data", binData));
```

Where binData is of type System.Data.Linq.Binary

what I dont understand is that when I look at the xml created it shows

```
<Data>"mydata"</Data>
```

instead of

```
<Data>mydata</Data>
```

why are there quotes and how do I get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `"mydata"` is because that is what the output of `System.Data.Linq.Binary`'s `ToString()` method gives you.

This is a simple way to get rid of them, although plenty of others exist:

```
string bindatastr = binData.ToString();
new XElement("Data", bindatastr.Substring(1, bindatastr.Length - 2));
```

Comment: yeah.. the data is coming from the db and the column is a varbinary but the data being stored is base64 encoded.. dont think varbinary was the best choice.

Comment: maybe not. I'm not good with DBs, but if you're storing the data as base 64 encoded, then I would go with some string type like varchar.